# Book about a girl who flies to an island and found out her mom was creating robot clones of children to be servants

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

It was like there was this girl who lived with her dad and her mom worked on an island and when the girl turned a certain age, she flew to the island to visit her by with this guy that she was I think childhood friends with or something who turned out to be a pilot and they flew to the island together and found her mom and discovered she was like creating robot clones of children to be servants and then they malfunctioned and something and then there was like this big fight against the robots or something like that. I know it was a series and the cover I think had a blue test tube/vial on the front and there was another book that I think was green.